# Start DispatcherTimer from N seconds, minutes, hours

Tags: c#, dispatchertimer

I have been searching for information and couldn't find any. My question is how to start DispatcherTimer from N seconds or minutes or hours. I mean currently it starts from 00:00:00 (also displayed in CurrentTime Label) but if I would like to start it from 00:00:30 (also display in CurrentTime Label), what should be differently?

To clarify it more... When I start an application I execute `StartWorkingTimeTodayTimer()`. Then I have a Label (`CurrentTime`) that is starting to show time of application runtime. Currently it starts from 00:00:00. I would like to display for example 00:00:30 at Start and then tick by one second as it is right now... so 00:00:30 -> 00:00:31 -> 00:00:32 -> 00:00:33 -> 00:00:34 ->

I have tried to play with:

```
DateTime x30SecsLater = StartTimeWholeDay.AddSeconds(30);
```

without success.

Current code:

```
private static DateTime StartTimeWholeDay;
private DispatcherTimer _dailyTimer;

public void StartWorkingTimeTodayTimer()
{
    StartTimeWholeDay = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime x30SecsLater = StartTimeWholeDay.AddSeconds(30);

    _dailyTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
    _dailyTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    _dailyTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
    {
        CurrentTime = (DateTime.Now - StartTimeWholeDay).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); // DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
    };
    _dailyTimer.Start();
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

I have tried already:

```
public void StartWorkingTimeTodayTimer()
{
    StartTimeWholeDay = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime x30SecsLater = StartTimeWholeDay.AddSeconds(30);

    _dailyTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
    _dailyTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    _dailyTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
    {
        CurrentTime = (DateTime.Now - x30SecsLater).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); // DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
    };
    _dailyTimer.Start();
}
```

but it calculates backwards...

[image]

It should go the other way 00:00:30 -> 00:00:31 -> 00:00:32 -> 00:00:33 -> 00:00:34 ->

Comment: how about using a `Task.Delay` before the timer start?

Comment: I was thinking about this some more, but the question is not fully clear: do you really want the timer to start with a 30 seconds delay, or do you want `CurrentTime` to have an offset of 30 seconds?

Comment: I don't want to start with delay. I just want  to start counting from certain time. Not from zero (00:00:00) as it is now but let's say from (00:00:30 or 00:03:00 or 03:00:50). Not in sense of timer should wait or start at certain time, just be able to specify time (number) from where to start counting. This should be something very simple, but I just can't figure how.

Comment: Well it seems you were already halfway there... Why didn't you try `CurrentTime = (DateTime.Now - x30SecsLater).<etc>`... that would start at "-30 seconds"... gives a hint.

Comment: Please see my edited question

Comment: @hatman please check this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13354/delayed-dispatcher-invoke

Comment: If it counts backwards, the minus operation is reversed: `(x30SecsLater - DateTime.Now)`. And you should use 'x30Secs**Earlier**'.

Comment: @hatman and try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740822/delayed-dispatch-invoke

Comment: @JHBonarius `CurrentTime = (x30MinsLater - DateTime.Now).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");` goes backwards as well

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to reproduce your issue in the mean time, but having a hard time getting WindowsBase.dll loaded in .NET 5

Comment: I think I get the issue: your custom `ToString` is not showing negative time... just wait and it will count up again... I'll form an answer soon.

Comment: I have dropped it to GitHub https://github.com/vadimffe/DispatherTimer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggeling a LONG time to get WPF running with a console (in .NET 5) ...I failed, so I'll give the answer using System.Timers. But you get the idea.

```cs
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace TimerExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DateTime _startTime;

        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs eea)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((eea.SignalTime - _startTime)
                .Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(29)) // 29, because the first trigger happens 1 sec after start
                .ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _startTime = DateTime.Now;
            var timer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 1000, // msec
                AutoReset = true,
            };
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timer.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace TimerExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DateTime _startTime;

        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs eea)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((eea.SignalTime - _startTime)
                .ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _startTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-29); // again 29 instead of 30
            var timer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 1000, // msec
                AutoReset = true,
            };
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timer.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Minus worked `DateTime x30SecsLater = StartTimeWholeDay.AddSeconds(-30);`

Comment: @hatman your should probably change the name of the variable in that case ;)