# Due to the use of Dispatcher,t he window still locks

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a program similar to chatbot in Wpf.
I have a stack where I create the user controls I have and enter them.
I have to use Net3.5 .
The response from the server is delayed.
The problem I have is when I type and send the textbox the server does not answer,
I can not type another question and the window is locked.
Did I use Dispatcher correctly?

[image: chatbot]

```
 private void send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        stack.Children.Add(new UserControl_Send()
        {
            DataSend = txt_input.Text,
            DateTimeBot = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
        });

        DispatchFit();

    }

    private void DispatchFit()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(ResponsServer), DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
    public void ResponsServer()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        stack.Children.Add(new UserControl_Receive()
        {
            DataRecive = get(txt_input.Text),
            DateTimeBot = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"),
        });
    }
```

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke runs the Action on the UI thread. You may want to take a look at Task.Run.

Comment: I can not use Task in .net3.5

Answer (score 0):

When that `ResponsServer()` callback is being processed on your UI thread, then that `Sleep` is elongating the amount of time that callback is taking to process (Sleep does not pump the UI's dispatcher message queue).

If you want your callback to be done after 3 seconds, then you need to use a timer, or you can use "async" to cause a delayed processing of your callback.

Look at this question: [Delayed Dispatch Invoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740822/delayed-dispatch-invoke)

Or use this to have a `BackgroundWorker` do the delay and then call your `ResponsServer` on the UI thread (not the best code as it creates a new `BackgroundWorker` each time).

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240274/Execute-later-for-delayed-action

Answer (score 0):

You are a little confused about the methods.
If I understand correctly, then Sleep is an emulation of the delay in the execution of sending a message to the server.

Then you need something like:

```cs
    private async void send_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        stack.Children.Add(new UserControl_Send()
        {
            DataSend = txt_input.Text,
            DateTimeBot = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
        });

        await ResponsServerAsync();

        stack.Children.Add(new UserControl_Receive()
        {
            DataRecive = get(txt_input.Text),
            DateTimeBot = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"),
        });
    }

    public async Task ResponsServerAsync()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
```

**For .Net Framework 3.5**

```cs
        private void send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            stack.Children.Add(new UserControl_Send()
            {
                DataSend = txt_input.Text,
                DateTimeBot = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")
            });

            Thread thread = new Thread(ResponsServer);
            thread.Start();

        }

        public void ResponsServer()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                StackChildrenAdd();
            }
            else
            {
                Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(StackChildrenAdd);
            }
    
        }
        private void StackChildrenAdd()
        {
            stack.Children.Add(new UserControl_Receive()
            {
                DataRecive = get(txt_input.Text),
                DateTimeBot = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"),
            });
        }
```

Comment: I can not use Task in .net3.5

Comment: .net **FRAMEWORK** 3.5 ?

Comment: I supplemented my answer with an variant for FW 3.5.
The implementation is very simplistic.
There is no marshaling for possible exceptions.
You have to add it yourself if you need it.

Comment: .net 3.5=.net framework 3.5

Comment: If   the output of my function to be the Task<string > value then what should I do?

Comment: I do not understand you.
You write that the target platform is .Net Framework 3.5.
Then how can you get Task?
Task can only be in .Net Framework 4+.

Comment: In my variant for 3.5, there is no Task and they cannot appear there.
If you have any Task, then your target platform is 4+.
And then you can use the first option from my answer.